# Can I create auto reply bot in Slack just using "Bot Users" without slack app?

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api

I want my bot to reply to particular keywords. As per the https://api.slack.com/bot-users, we can create custom bot without slack app. But how do I get OATH tokens without an app but just Customer Bot User?

Comment: were u able to create the custom bot ?

Answer (score 0):

That works. After installing a Custom Bot you automatically get the corresponding OAUTH token for that bot. Just go to "Manage Apps" / "Custom Integrations" / "Bots". Then click on your settings for your bot to get your token.